# Laravel events triggers, Echo listens to it but doesn't go through the function

Tags: laravel, events, broadcast

Controllers/UserController.php

```
event(new UserEntered($myReserve));
```

Events/UserEntered.php

```
public function __construct($hisReserve)
{
    $this->hisReserve = $hisReserve;
}
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PrivateChannel('same-user.'.$this->hisReserve);
}
```

routes/channels.php

```
Broadcast::channel('same-user.{hisReserve}', function ($user, $hisReserve) {
    return true;
});
```

js/bootstrap.js

```
user_id = 1; //as an example
window.Echo.private('same-user.' + user_id)
    .listen('UserEntered', (update) => {
        // it doesn't trigger here...
        console.log(update);
        alert('alert');
    });
```

In console it is showing `Event: App\Events\UserEntered - Channel: private-same-user.1` but when I want to listen to it, it doesn't go through the function. actually UserEntered is not triggered. My first issue is that why it doesn't go through the function? and my second issue is that is it possible to use an object as parameter instead of an integer user_id there?

**Update**

SHOCKED! The `same-user` that I'm listening to doesn't work but other channel which name is `valid-user` had been working but again it is working when I changed it to `return false`. Is something cached in Laravel?

Comment: Within your `channel.php`, should you not be creating a condition to make sure that `$hisReserve` is being checked properly? Also, have you attempted to get this working using a normal `Channel` call (as opposed to `PrivateChanel`).

Comment: Exactly because I wanted to check whether it is checking the condition or not I set `valid-user` to always return false however the result is authenticated user. and vice-versa for the other channel which is `same-user` although I have set it to true, it is not working! or let's say it is working but Echo can't get the data. I'm using PrivateChannel.

Comment: Have you check to see if there is a `auth` issue in your console log? I came across this issue and got a `419` error.

Comment: I have `Route::any('broadcasting/auth', function () {
    return 'authd';
});` for that. but the shock part is the time when I return false for `valid-user`, it says `authenticated` and return true for `same-user` it doesn't return anything!!

Comment: Thats concerning. Will look out for solutions